# Why is my ionic program not showing a list?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

EDIT: THIS IS SOLVED! CHECK THE spells.service.ts FILE FOR THE FIX

I am building a Dungeons and Dragons helper app, and I am having some trouble getting a list of spells to show up in the app.

It's written using Ionic framework and Angular style.

Here's a sample of the HTML file (tab3.page.html) that should be showing all of the spells:

```
<ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>
        <h2>Cantrips</h2>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let spell of (spells | async)">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label float:left>{{ spell.name }}</ion-label>
        <ion-text float:right>{{ spell.level }}</ion-text>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item-group>
```

The "spells" call is an Observable Array, defined here in tab3.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Spell } from '../interfaces/Spell.interface';
import { SpellsService } from '../services/spells.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {

  public spells: Observable<Spell[]>;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    public service: SpellsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spells = this.service.getAllSpells();
    console.log(this.spells[15].name);
  }

  viewSpell(spell) {
    //nothing rn until I can make the spell-detail tab
  }

}
```

The console.log shows that it is correctly reading the getAllSpells, which is defined here in spells.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Spell } from '../interfaces/Spell.interface';
import { SPELLS } from 'src/assets/data/spellList';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpellsService {
  
  private spells: Observable<Spell[]>;
  public NUM_OF_SPELLS = 487;

  constructor() {
    this.spells = new Observable<Spell[]>();

    for (let i = 0; i < this.NUM_OF_SPELLS; i++) {
      this.spells[i] = (SPELLS.spellList[i]);
    }
  }

  getAllSpells(): Observable<Spell[]> {
    return this.spells;
  }
}
```

EDIT: HAD TO REPLACE SOME CODE IN THIS FILE, HERE IS THE WORKING UPDATED VERSION OF spells.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Spell } from '../interfaces/Spell.interface';
import { SPELLS } from 'src/assets/data/spellList';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpellsService {
  
  private spells: Observable<Spell[]>;
  public NUM_OF_SPELLS = 487;

  constructor() {
    this.spells = new Observable<Spell[]>();

    this.spells = of(SPELLS.spellList);
  }

  getAllSpells(): Observable<Spell[]> {
    return this.spells;
  }
}
```

And finally, the SPELLS that it is reading is from the file spellList.ts:

```
export const SPELLS = {
    spellList: [
        {
            "name": "Abi-Dalzim's Horrid Wilting",
            "damage": [
                "12d8"
            ],
            "damageType": "necrotic damage",
            "level": 8,
            "castTime": "1 action",
            "damageLevel": [
                8
            ],
            "duration": "instantaneous",
            "damaging": true,
            "description": "You draw the moisture from every creature in a 30-foot cube centered on a point you choose within range. Each creature in that area must make a Constitution saving throw. Constructs and undead aren’t affected, and plants and water elementals make this saving throw with disadvantage. A creature takes 12d8 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.<br>Nonmagical plants in the area that aren’t creatures, such as trees and shrubs, wither and die instantly.",
            "school": "necromancy",
            "ritual": false,
            "range": "150 feet",
            "attackRoll": "save",
            "concentration": false,
            "components": [
                "V",
                "S",
                "M (a bit of sponge)"
            ]
        },
        {
            "damageType": "varied damage",
            "concentration": false,
            "damage": [
                "1d6",
                "2d6",
                "3d6",
                "4d6",
                "5d6",
                "6d6",
                "7d6",
                "8d6",
                "9d6"
            ],
            "level": 1,
            "components": [
                "S"
            ],
            "duration": "1 round",
            "castTime": "1 reaction (when taking acid, cold, fire, lightning, or thunder damage)",
            "damageLevel": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6,
                7,
                8,
                9
            ],
            "damaging": true,
            "ritual": false,
            "name": "Absorb Elements",
            "range": "self",
            "description": "The spell captures some of the incoming energy, lessening its effect on you and storing it for your next melee attack. You have resistance to the triggering damage type until the start of your next turn. Also, the first time you hit with a melee attack on your next turn, the target takes an extra 1d6 damage of the triggering type, and the spell ends.<br>At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 2nd level or higher, the extra damage increases by 1d6 for each slot level above 1st.",
            "school": "abjuration",
            "attackRoll": "see spell"
        }
  ]
}
```

(This is just a small sample of what the rest of the page looks like, theres close to 500 of these)

I have written this by looking at a similar example from a class I've taken, and I was able to get it to work before. The only change is that I am now reading the spellList from a local file instead of from an online database.

Would love any and all help!

Comment: Instead of looping through an array in the service, why not just do this: `this.spells = of(SPELLS.spellList);` to load the spells?

Comment: @R.Richards This did it! Thank you so much for the help!